# python-docx style_id error while creating a word document

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, python-docx

I'm following the tutorial available on [python-docx](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) site to create a MS-Word document but I'm getting an error:

```
M:\Sites>python word.py
C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22\Python\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\sty
les.py:54: UserWarning: style lookup by style_id is deprecated. Use style name a
s key instead.
  warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

word.py

```
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Inches
    import json

    document = Document()

    document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

    p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
    p.add_run('bold').bold = True
    p.add_run(' and some ')
    p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

    document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
    document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='IntenseQuote')

    document.add_paragraph(
        'first item in unordered list', style='ListBullet'
    )
    document.add_paragraph(
        'first item in ordered list', style='ListNumber'
    )

    document.add_page_break()

    document.save('demo.docx')
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simple but hard to debug. Just add space between words in style.

> document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='**IntenseQuote**')

Changes to:

> document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='**Intense Quote**')