# How to add table border to word doc using python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to create a word document using docx module of Python.
However I am unable to add table border to it.

My code is as below:

```
    import docx
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Pt
    doc = Document('C:/Users/Vinny/Desktop/Python/Template.docx')
    doc.add_paragraph('Changes:')

    doc.add_paragraph('Metrics:')
    #add table
    table = doc.add_table(rows = 4, cols = 2, style='TableGrid')
    doc.save('C:/Users/Vinny/Desktop/Python/rel.docx')
```

But it throws error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\Desktop\Python\abc.py", line 14, in <module>
    table = doc.add_table(rows = 4, cols = 2, style='TableGrid')
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 100, in add_table
    table.style = style
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 134, in style
    style_or_name, WD_STYLE_TYPE.TABLE
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 76, in get_style_id
    return self.styles.get_style_id(style_or_name, style_type)
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 113, in get_style_id
    return self._get_style_id_from_name(style_or_name, style_type)
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 143, in _get_style_id_from_name
    return self._get_style_id_from_style(self[style_name], style_type)
  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("no style with name '%s'" % key)
KeyError: "no style with name 'TableGrid'"
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Make sure you read this page in the documentation and the one immediately following it (using the Next button): http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html

Comment: It worked fine and created the desired document. I added table grid to the template, deleted and saved it. Works fine. Only thing is displays a warning message  every time.

Warning message goes like: 

"  File "C:\Users\Vinny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 54
    warn(msg, UserWarning)
UserWarning: style lookup by style_id is deprecated. Use style name as key instead.s : "

Comment: What's the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: @VinnyKaur Check this link to fix your warning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973277/python-docx-style-id-error-while-creating-a-word-document

Comment: ah ! I checked that, and it worked, Thank you @MarutiMohanty .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify border appearance in tables using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685458/specify-border-appearance-in-tables-using-python-docx)

Answer (score 8):

Try with a space:

`table = doc.add_table(rows = 4, cols = 2, style='Table Grid')`

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
```

also add the space to make `style='Table Grid'`

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh Is there a reason you think that it doesn't work?  It definitely works for me as well for a few others that have responded to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using space:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3, style='Table Grid')
```