# docx module: UserWarning: style lookup by style_id is deprecated. Use style name as key instead.

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running a code here:

```
import docx, os
os.chdir('C:\\PythonScripts')
doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph('Hello World!')
doc.paragraphs[0].style = 'Heading6'
doc.save('test.docx')
```

and I get that warning in the title. The script still works, but I think I'm doing something outdated in the newest updates. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python-docx style\_id error while creating a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973277/python-docx-style-id-error-while-creating-a-word-document)

Answer (score 6):

You may change your

```
doc.paragraphs[0].style = 'Heading6'
```

to

```
doc.paragraphs[0].style = 'Heading 6'
```

and it shall work just fine.